# How can I remove the space under v-app-bar in vuejs?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

How can I remove the space under v-app-bar?

the header part
**User_Header.vue**

```
<template>
<v-app id="user_header">
    <v-app-bar app color="#8a0303" dark>
        <h1>this is app bar</h1>
    </v-app-bar>
</v-app>

</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "User_Header"
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

the part that i call header
**User_Dashboard.vue**

```
<template>
  <v-app id="user_dashboard">
      <User_Header />
      <div>
          <h1>Test</h1>
      </div>
 </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import User_Header from '../components/layout/User_Header'
export default {
    name: "User_Dashboard",
    components: {
        User_Header
    }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

there is the big gap in my result

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSvdf.png)

Comment: you mean.. left padding you want to remove?

Comment: @NileshPatel I would like to remove the space between bar and my content one. I have no idea why there is so much empty space right there even though I never wrote any code about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/application/) on the Vuetify documentation, you are rendering v-app twice when it should only be rendered once in your application.

Instead of wrapping your header in `<v-app>` tags replace them with div tags.

```
<template>
<div id="user_header">
    <v-app-bar app color="#8a0303" dark>
        <h1>this is app bar</h1>
    </v-app-bar>
</div>
</template>
```